# which are the best machine learning models for time series data

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, rnn

I have real-time data of a production line that shows when the machine incurs downtime(i.e machine stops functioning). My idea is to predict the next downtime of the machine in well advance. what machine learning algorithm will be best for such case?